# Longest slope oriented to north?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I need a help with my homework.
I have created digital elevation model from the shapefile. In QGis(Grass plugin)

[image]

This is how far i can go. I have to find the longest slope oriented to North.
I know I have to use r.slope and r.aspect modules, but how can I use it?

Thanks!

Comment: An analysis of aspect will provide you with all of your north-facing slopes, and an analysis of slope will allow you to find areas of elevation change. You'll need to define what your slope criteria (e.g. anything > 0degrees).

Comment: you need to define what you mean by "North facing": is it aspect of 0 or between -180 and 180 ?